# Multiple Sass projects in Netbeans

Tags: drupal, netbeans, sass

I'm developing a Drupal theme and a module in the same Netbeans project.

My preprocessors configuration is working and I'm able to write scss files and have them compiled automatically.
I created a **config.rb** file at the root of the project but I'm able to configure just a single proproject_path

```
project_path = '[...absolute-path...]\sites\all\modules\mymodule'
```

Watching multiple folders is easy through Netbeans but how do I manage multiple Sass projects?
I can watch multiple folders but can't output multiple files!

How can I have sass compiler to create a css in the module folder and a different one in the theme folder

```
\sites\all\modules\mymodule\scss\mymodule.scss ->   \sites\all\modules\mymodule\css\mymodule.css
\sites\all\themes\mytheme\scss\style.scss      ->   \sites\all\themes\mytheme\css\style.css
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't say if what you ask is possible, I don't think so, but what you can do is to put a `config.rb` in each directory you want to watch, then right click the dir in Netbeans and select "Open in terminal", then in the terminal do a "compass watch".

This seems to be the way to go if you want relative paths for the source files from the theme dir as well.